# Xtify + Worklight 6.1 integration in android environment

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, xtify

We have been working on the integration between worklight and xtify for push notifications. We are using version 2.3.2 for xtify sdk since latest version (2.4.2) made the app failed because a class not found exception.

The logic for using xtify has been added to the native code of the WL hybrid application as follows:

```
public class XtifyWL extends WLDroidGap {
    public static final String XTIFY_APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx";
    public static final String PROJECT_NUM = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // This is the Google Project Number


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStart();
        XtifySDK.start(getApplicationContext(), XTIFY_APP_KEY, PROJECT_NUM);
    }
```

We are receiving the push notifications, but they are duplicated. We received one notification for worklight that fails when you try to open it, and one more for the native application thats works correctly.

How can we fix it?

About the issue with the SDK 2.4.2.2

The exception with SDK 2.4.2.2 is:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.xtify.sdk.db.Provider: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xtify.sdk.db.Provider
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4609)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4178)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:134)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xtify.sdk.db.Provider
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4594)
... 12 more
```

The only place where we see that class is in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider android:name="com.xtify.sdk.db.Provider" android:authorities="com.XtifyApp.XTIFY_PROVIDER" android:exported="false" />
```

If we comment that line it fails with the next use of any class of the SDK. We have added the sdk .jar file to the libs folder of the android project and to the build path of the android project.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found why when we send a push notification, we see them duplicated (two notifications icons on the top).

It was an error in the AndroidManifest.xml, we added all the Xtify GCM configuration and we also left the worklight GCM configuration so we where registering two receivers.

But we have still the issue of "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException" when we try to use the latest Xtify SDK. Athough at least receiving simple notifications seems to work with the SDK 2.3.2.

This is the correct AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.XtifyApp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">  
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>  
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>  
<!-- Push permissions -->  
<permission android:name="com.XtifyApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.XtifyApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />


<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon"> 
    <activity android:name=".XtifyApp" android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTask"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.XtifyApp.XtifyApp.NOTIFICATION"/>  
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </activity>  

    <activity android:name="com.worklight.common.WLPreferences" android:label="Worklight Settings"></activity>

    <!-- Start XTIFY -->


    <provider android:name="com.xtify.sdk.db.Provider" android:authorities="com.XtifyApp.XTIFY_PROVIDER" android:exported="false" />

    <receiver android:name=".XtifyNotifier" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.xtify.sdk.NOTIFIER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.xtify.sdk.c2dm.C2DMBroadcastReceiver" >
        <intent-filter android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.XtifyApp" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.XtifyApp" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver android:name="com.xtify.sdk.NotifActionReceiver" />
    <receiver android:name="com.xtify.sdk.wi.AlarmReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.xtify.sdk.location.LocationUpdateService" />
    <service android:name="com.xtify.sdk.c2dm.C2DMIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.xtify.sdk.alarm.MetricsIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.xtify.sdk.alarm.TagIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.xtify.sdk.alarm.RegistrationIntentService" />
    <service android:name="com.xtify.sdk.alarm.LocationIntentService" />

    <!-- END XTIFY -->


   <!--  Start Worklight GCM configuration -->
   <!--  
    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService"/>  
    <service android:name=".ForegroundService"/>  

    <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">             
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>  
            <category android:name="com.XtifyApp"/> 
        </intent-filter>  
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>  
            <category android:name="com.XtifyApp"/> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver> 
    -->
    <!--  END Worklight GCM configuration -->

</application> 
</manifest>
```