# Xtify integration in Worklight / Dojo

Tags: java, android, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, xtify

I have an app developed in Worklight 6.2, using DoJo framework, and I want to integrate it with Xtify.
By reading the integration tutorial, I found a problem in the 7th step:

> Step 7:
>
> 1.Perform the following steps to edit your main activity class: Add an import for com.ibm.mobilepush.cordova.MobilePushCordovaActivity.
>
> 2.Make your main activity override MobilePushCordovaActivity instead of
>    CordovaActivity.
>
> 3.If you override the onSaveInstanceState method or the
>    onNewIntent, make sure you call the super class method.

However, since I am working with a DoJo application, my Main Activity class already extends anoter class:

```
import com.worklight.androidgap.WLDroidGap;

public class DojoApp extends WLDroidGap {
    private static WebView webViewOverlay;
    public static Activity thisapp; 
    private static final String TAG = "DojoApp";
    private static ProgressDialog progressBar;
    ...
```

How can I proceed with this integration? I was thinking that maybe I could extend two different classes, but that doens't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look into this post:
[Xtify + Worklight 6.1 integration in android environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24042595/xtify-worklight-6-1-integration-in-android-environment)

You probably need to add

```
public static final String XTIFY_APP_KEY = "xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxxxxx";
public static final String PROJECT_NUM = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // This is the Google Project Number
```

and append this line to your onStart() method:

```
XtifySDK.start(getApplicationContext(), XTIFY_APP_KEY, PROJECT_NUM);
```

I would also add these two methods:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {       
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    MobilePushCordovaPluginUtils.onSaveInstanceState(this, outState);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {     
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    MobilePushCordovaPluginUtils.onNewIntent(this, intent);
}
```